# Why can't we use Yoneda Lemma to get a representation theorem for Rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm new to category theory.

I am trying to understand how Yoneda Lemma is a generalization of representations theorems in algebra.

Cayley theorem can be interpreted as a instance for the case where the category $\mathcal{C}$ is the one with only one element $*$ and  arrows are iso arrows that correspond to the elements of $G$ (i.e., it is a grupoid. I am using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) wiki-page as reference) . From the Yoneda Lemma we can establish the Cayley theorem.

But there is another result from algebra that says that there isn't a representation theorem for Rings in general. (I don't understand why this is the case, I just heard it). There is only a representation theorem if we restrict to the context of Boolean algebras (the Stone Theorem).

Why we can't just apply Yoneda lemma in some way to get a general result for Ring theory? (Not the Stone theorem) I mean, in the context of groups we've used the grupoid category. Why we can't consider something like it in Rings and apply the Yoneda? Some category like a ``ringoid'' (sorry for this word).

Maybe there is to much happening here, but I think some intuition of this might help understand better the nature of Yoneda Lemma.

Edit: the discussion in the comments and in this [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27971/why-is-there-no-cayleys-theorem-for-rings/27979#27979) pointed me that the result I mentioned is false: there is a Cayley on Rings. I will not edit the original text question. So now I think the question is:

> How do we get this version of Cayley on Rings with Yoneda?

I still very confused with all this new information, and I didn't understand the answer there.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/27979

Comment: The issue is that if you can't say more precisely what is meant by "there is no representation theorem for rings", it's difficult to see how to fix it, with Yoneda lemma or not.

Comment: @CaptainLama, well yes. I was thinking about something like Cayley on Rings in general. But now with the link above I am even more confused, it seems there is some kind of Cayley theorem for Rings.

Comment: @Lostdefinition Yes, there absolutely is. It's quite unclear what your half-remembered negative result was getting at.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *preadditive* category is a category $\mathcal{A}$ together with the structure of an abelian group of each set $\mathcal{A}(A, B)$, in such a way that that all composition functions
$$
  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, B)
  ×
  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(B, C)
  \longrightarrow
  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, C) \,,
  \quad
  (f, g) \longmapsto g ∘ f
$$
are $ℤ$-bilinear. More explicitly,
$$
  g ∘ (f_1 + f_2) = g ∘ f_1 + g ∘ f_2 \,,
  \quad
  (g_1 + g_2) ∘ f = g_1 ∘ f + g_2 ∘ f \,.
$$

For any object $A$ in a preadditive category $\mathcal{A}$, the set $\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{A}}(A)$ becomes a ring:
its underlying abelian group is $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, A)$, and its multiplication is given by composition of endomorphisms.

There are two important examples of preadditive categories are the following:

- The category $\mathbf{Ab}$ of abelian groups.
- Every ring $R$ can be regarded as a preadditive category $\mathcal{R}$ consisting of only a single object $\ast$, with $\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{R}}(A) = R$.

For any preadditive category $\mathcal{A}$, its opposite category $\mathcal{A}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is again preadditive.

---

A functor $F \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ between preadditive categories $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is called *additive* if for any two objects $A$ and $B$, the map
$$
  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, B)
  \xrightarrow{\enspace F \enspace}
  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{B}}( F(A), F(B) )
$$
is a homomorphism of groups.
If $F$ is such an additive functor, then for every object $A$ of $\mathcal{A}$, the map
$$
  \mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{A}}(A)
  \xrightarrow{\enspace F \enspace}
  \mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{B}}(F(A))
$$
is a homomorphism of rings.

An important example of additive functors are represented functors:
for every object $A$ of a preadditive category $\mathcal{A}$, both
$$
  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, -)
  \colon
  \mathcal{A} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Ab}
$$
and
$$
  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(-, A)
  \colon
  \mathcal{A}^{\mathrm{op}} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Ab}
$$
are additive.

---

Given two functors
$$
  F, G \colon \mathcal{A} \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}
$$
with $\mathcal{B}$ preadditive, the set of natural transformation from $F$ to $G$, denoted by $\mathrm{Nat}(F, G)$, becomes an abelian group with addition given by
$$
  (α + β)_A ≔ α_α + β_A
$$
for every two natural transformations $α$ and $β$ and every object $A$ of $\mathcal{A}$.

It follows that the functor category $[\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}]$ inherits a preadditive structure from $\mathcal{B}$.

---

One can now state a version of Yoneda’s lemma for preadditive categories:

> (Yoneda’s lemma for preadditive categories.)
> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a preadditive category, let $F$ be an additive functor from $\mathcal{A}^{\mathrm{op}}$ to $\mathbf{Ab}$, and let $A$ be an object of $\mathcal{A}$.
> The map
> $$
>   \mathrm{Nat}( \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(-, A), F )
>   \longrightarrow
>   F(A) \,,
>   \quad
>   α \longmapsto α_A(\mathrm{id}_A)
> $$
> is an isomorphism of abelian groups that is natural in both $A$ and $F$.

As a consequence, one gets a Yoneda embedding for preadditive categories.

> (Yoneda embedding for preadditive categories)
> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a preadditive category.
> Then
> $$
>   \mathcal{A}
>   \longrightarrow
>   [\mathcal{A}^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathbf{Ab}] \,,
>   \quad
>   A
>   \longmapsto
>   \mathrm{Hom}(-, A)
> $$
> is an additive embedding of categories.

As a consequence, one find that for every object $A$ of a preadditive category $\mathcal{A}$, the map
$$
  \mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{A}}(A)
  \longrightarrow
  \mathrm{End}_{[\mathcal{A}^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathbf{Ab}]}( 
    \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(-, A)
  )
$$
is an isomorphism of rings.

---

Given a ring $R$, we can form the corresponding preadditive category $\mathcal{R}$ consisting of only a single element $\ast$ with $\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{R}}(\ast) = R$.
A functor from $\mathcal{R}^{\mathrm{op}}$ to $\mathbf{Ab}$ is then “the same” as a right $R$-module.
The right $R$-module corresponding to the represented functor $\mathcal{R}(-, \ast)$ is just $R$ itself.

Yoneda’s lemma gives us isomorphisms of rings
$$
  R
  =
  \mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{R}}(\ast)
  ≅
  \mathrm{End}_{[\mathcal{R}^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathbf{Ab}]}( 
    \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{R}}(-, \ast)
  )
  ≅
  \mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{Mod}\text{-}R}(R) \,.
$$
This overall isomorphism sends any element $r$ of $R$ to the map
$$
  R \longrightarrow R \,,
  \quad
  x \longmapsto r x \,,
$$
which is indeed a homomorphism of right $R$-modules.

The ring $\mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{Mod}\text{-}R}(R)$ is a subring of $\mathrm{End}_{ℤ}(R)$.
Therefore, every ring $R$ can be realized as a subring of $\mathrm{End}_ℤ(A)$ for some abelian group $A$.
This is Cayley’s theorem for rings.

Comment: That is very nice answer! Thank you for the work you put into it.